# Rejecting invocation, expected 86 argument registers, method signature has 88 or more in Kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class for fetching data from server like this:

```
@Entity
data class Rates(
    @PrimaryKey
    val AED: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val AFN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ALL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val AMD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ANG: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val AOA: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ARS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val AUD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val AWG: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val AZN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BAM: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BBD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BDT: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BGN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BHD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BIF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BMD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BND: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BOB: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BRL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BSD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BTC: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BTN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BWP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BYN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BYR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val BZD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CAD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CDF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CHF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CLF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CLP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CNY: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val COP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CRC: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CUC: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CUP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CVE: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val CZK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val DJF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val DKK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val DOP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val DZD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val EGP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ERN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ETB: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val EUR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val FJD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val FKP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GBP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GEL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GGP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GHS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GIP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GMD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GNF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GTQ: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val GYD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val HKD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val HNL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val HRK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val HTG: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val HUF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val IDR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ILS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val IMP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val INR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val IQD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val IRR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ISK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val JEP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val JMD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val JOD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val JPY: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KES: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KGS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KHR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KMF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KPW: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KRW: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KWD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KYD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val KZT: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LAK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LBP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LKR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LRD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LSL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LTL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LVL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val LYD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MAD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MDL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MGA: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MKD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MMK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MNT: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MOP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MRO: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MUR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MVR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MWK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MXN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MYR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val MZN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val NAD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val NGN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val NIO: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val NOK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val NPR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val NZD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val OMR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PAB: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PEN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PGK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PHP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PKR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PLN: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val PYG: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val QAR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val RON: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val RSD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val RUB: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val RWF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SAR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SBD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SCR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SDG: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SEK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SGD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SHP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SLL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SOS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SRD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val STD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SVC: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SYP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val SZL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val THB: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TJS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TMT: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TND: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TOP: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TRY: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TTD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TWD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val TZS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val UAH: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val UGX: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val USD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val UYU: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val UZS: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val VND: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val VUV: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val WST: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XAF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XAG: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XAU: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XCD: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XDR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XOF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val XPF: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val YER: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ZAR: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ZMK: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ZMW: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE,
    val ZWL: Double = Double.MIN_VALUE
): Serializable
```

when I run the app it crashes with the following error:
**Rejecting invocation, expected 86 argument registers, method signature has 88 or more**
If I decrease the number of objects from the class the crash doesnt happen anymore. But for my project requirements I can not reduce the objects, I need all of them. How can I get rid of this error and run the app successfully?

Comment: you might find some helpful hints [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1393) and [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/632)

Comment: I have an example of my currency converting application which might be useful for you https://github.com/Steyrix/Currency-Converter-MVI-Compose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rethink your design.  A single class with 80+ values in a constructor is a bad idea.  Especially given it looks like what you're trying to do is currency conversion.  In that case, this is absolutely not what you'd want-  you're almost never going to be doing a hardcoded lookup of a single currency where you'd go rates.usd.  Most of the time you're going to take the currency code as a parameter.  What you probably want is a `Map<String, Double>` where the currency code is mapped to a rate.